# Jquery append multiple times with custom ID names? Can someone send me in the right direction

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery and I'm trying to create a filter. 
I have a filter button to add another filter, this all works but the P get's the same ID. Which is logical.

Can someone send me in the right direction to give each ID it's own number? 
Say someone clicks the button 10 times, each ID gets a 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 so I can target these again with jquery.

This is my script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Filter2").click(function(){
      $("#Filter2div").css("display", "inline;");
    $("#FilterP").append('<p id="and-or-"><p ID="Attribute2-"></p><p 
id="Operator-Value2-"></p><p ID="Filter_Value2-"></p>' );
$("#Filter2div").append('<br><select ID="andor" onchange="Andor(this)"> <option value="Select">Select</option><option value="-and">-and</option><option value="-or">-or</option></select><input ID="AttributeValue2" Placeholder="Filterable Property"></input><select ID="Operator2" onchange="PS_Operator2(this)"><option value="Select">Select</option><option value="-eq">-eq</option><option value="-ne">-ne</option><option value="-like">-like</option><option value="-notlike">-notlike</option><option value="-ge">-ge</option><option value="-le">-le</option></select><input ID="Filterable_Value2" Placeholder="Filterable Value"></input>'  );

 });
});
```

And the HTML part:

```
<div ID="Full_Filter">
<pre><p ID="OptionValue"></p> -Filter {<p ID="Attribute"></p><p id="Operator- 
Value"></p><p ID="Filter_Value"></p><p id="FilterP"></p>}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand how your code is supposed to work, as it relies on a click function on a element that doesn't exist in you HTML here: `$("#Filter2").click(function(){`.

However, this is a basic example on how you can do this using a class to select your dynamically created elements and jQuery's `length` to count them and create a new id based on this count:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var container = $('#container');
  $('#addButton').on('click', function(){
    var count = $('.addedElement').length;
    container.append('<div id="id-' + count + '" class="addedElement">Element with id "id-' + count + '"</div>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="addButton">ADD</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thank you, didn't know a "Count" would be enough.

Comment: @baswijdenesdotcom you just have to keep in mind that this will not work if you want to dynamically remove items that are not the last id, in that case, you must either use a global count variable or parse all the ids to get the higher value